# Method setCurrentState must be called on the main thread, Android, Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Android studio shows errors in the lines

`REPOSITORY.insert(note){ onSuccess() }`

in the "AddNewNoteFragmentViewModel" and in the lines

`viewModel.insert(AppNote(name = name, text = text)){        view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.action_addNewNoteFragment_to_mainFragment)}`

in the file "AddNewNoteFragment"

I realized that the error is related to streams, but I do not know how to solve it

If anyone knows, please help, I could not find anything worthwhile on the Internet

**AddNewNoteFragment**

```
  package com.example.notes.fragments.add_new_note

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import com.example.notes.R
import com.example.notes.databinding.FragmentAddNewNoteBinding
import com.example.notes.model.AppNote
import com.example.notes.utilits.showToast


class AddNewNoteFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentAddNewNoteBinding? = null
    val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var viewModel: AddNewNoteFragmentViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentAddNewNoteBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root
        return view

    }


    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        initialization()
    }

    private fun initialization() {
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(AddNewNoteFragmentViewModel::class.java)

        binding.buttonAddNote.setOnClickListener {

            val name = binding.inputNameNote.text.toString()
            val text = binding.inputTextNote.text.toString()

            if (name.isEmpty()){

                showToast("Введите имя заметки")

            } else{

                viewModel.insert(AppNote(name = name, text = text)){
                    view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.action_addNewNoteFragment_to_mainFragment)
                }

            }

        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

**AddNewNoteFragmentViewModel**

```
package com.example.notes.fragments.add_new_note

import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.notes.model.AppNote
import com.example.notes.utilits.REPOSITORY
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class AddNewNoteFragmentViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    fun insert(note: AppNote,onSuccess:()-> Unit) =
        viewModelScope.launch (Dispatchers.IO){
            REPOSITORY.insert(note){
                onSuccess()
            }
        }

}
```

**Error screen**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL4hN.png)

Comment: What is your `RESPOSITORY`? Can you include that code?

Comment: I think the problem is you are trying the navigate from fragment to other while the coroutine is still running by calling onSuccess at the mid of the coroutine process

Comment: add the navigation line as below.




viewModelScope.launch (Dispatchers.Main){

view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.action_addNewNoteFragment_to_mainFragment)

}

Comment: Thanks to everyone who responded :) I solved the problem

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 6):

Problem solved
In **AddNewNoteFragmentViewModel** requires `Dispatchers.IO` to be changed to `Dispatchers.Main`

Answer (score 1):

```
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("keyDashBoard", "No")
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.navigation_home_details,bundle)
    }, 6000)
```

You can add this in fragment.